# why my footer is not increasing from its edges in html?

Tags: html, css

please help me i am writing html document and having a problem. can you tell why my footer is not increasing from its edges even if i select width 100% please help
this code is not compelte i have not given css please click link at bottom to see my problem

```
enter code <footer class="footer-distributed">

        <div class="footer-left">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b7/b3/96/b7b396047648c1baa436937d0afdfa76.jpg">
            <h3>About <span>just do it</span></h3>

            <p class="footer-links">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                |
                <a href="#">Blog</a>
                |
                <a href="#">About</a>
                |
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </p>
    <hr>

            <p class="footer-company-name">
      copyright © 2021 kaustubh krishna</p>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-center">
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                  <p><span>find about us at our social media</p>
            
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                <p><a href="#">support@justdoit.com</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-right">
            <p class="footer-company-about">
                <span>About the company</span>
                We offer freelance services for you and your company </p>
            </div>
    <div class="footer-icons">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </div> here
```

link of document:  https://codepen.io/kaustubh0711/pen/XWNdNrv?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .small-container div has a max-width css style keeping it from taking up the entire width of the screen.  You'll also have to remove the left and right padding from it or else you'll still have gaps on each side of your footer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the `.small-container` and `.row`, they affect the footer.

```html
<div class="small-container">
  <div class="row">
    ... content ...       
  </div>
</div>
<!-----footer---->
```